# Can't get pgAdmin 4 debugger to work on a specific fn

Tags: pgadmin

I'm trying to debug a function on Postgres 10 (on Debian) using pgAdmin 4.20 (on a Mac).

I can debug some fns OK so the debugger must be set up OK, but when I try to debug the fn I'm having problems with, I get a message

"error while starting debugging listener"

I can't find anything that helps explain/fix this. Anything I should check?

Comment: The same thing is happening to me. So far I have not been able to pinpoint the cause for that...